# Sum columns based on condition

Tags: r, sum, multiple-columns

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
scaf   pos   ref   A-1   A-2   A-3   A-4   B-1   B-2   B-3   B-4
MT1   11722   A    330    0     0     0    111    0    0     0
MT1   11723   T     0    230    0     8     0    18    0     2
MT1   11724   A    222    2     6     0    56     8    0     0
```

Here is what I want to do. For each row:

if ref = A, sum columns A-2 to A-4 and B-2 to B-4

if ref = T, sum columns A-1, A-3 and A4 together and B-1, B3 and B-4

if ref = C, sum columns A-1, A-2 and A4 together. Same with B columns

if ref = G, sum columns A-1 to A-3 and B1 to B3.

You would end up with:

```
scaf   pos   ref   A    B
MT1   11722   A    0    0
MT1   11723   T    8    2
MT1   11724   A    8    8
```

Any idea how I could do that? Keep in mind that I have about 100 columns and thousands of rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `dplyr::case_when' can be as:

```
df %>% mutate(A = case_when(
      ref == "A" ~ A.2+A.4,
      ref == "T" ~ A.1+A.3+A.4,
      ref == "C" ~ A.1+A.2+A.4,
      ref == "G" ~ A.1+A.3
                           )) %>% 
        mutate(B = case_when(
        ref == "A" ~ B.2+B.4,
        ref == "T" ~ B.1+B.3+B.4,
        ref == "C" ~ B.1+B.2+B.4,
        ref == "G" ~ B.1+B.3
                     )) %>%
      select(scaf, pos, ref, A, B)

#   scaf   pos ref A B
# 1  MT1 11722   A 0 0
# 2  MT1 11723   T 8 2
# 3  MT1 11724   A 2 8
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"scaf   pos   ref   A-1   A-2   A-3   A-4   B-1   B-2   B-3   B-4
MT1   11722   A    330    0     0     0    111    0    0     0
MT1   11723   T     0    230    0     8     0    18    0     2
MT1   11724   A    222    2     6     0    56     8    0     0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This definitely works. However, I have 96 columns so it might be tedious to take this approach and write everything down. If you have any ideas on how to make this quicker, please let me know. Thanks again!